# AWS LoadBalancer with vanity name servers

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, nameservers, amazon-route53

I want to build php application that responds to more than 1 domain and I want to have vanity name servers to point these domains to. For instance I would like to have
ns1.mydomain.com and ns2.mydomain.com pointing to my load balancer and I'm wondering what is the best way to do this. One option is to have glue records with my registrar and to create ns1.mydomain.com and ns2.mydomain.com as glue records however the problem I'm facing with this is that glue records can only be associated with IP address, but the load balancers in amazon don't have statis IP address, instead they are using something similar to: eLB-33426556007.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com.

Can someone recommend what is the best way to have branded name servers for amazon loadbalancer?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve as in the end result? Have you considered using Route53? Why can you not point a CNAME to the ELB?

Comment: Yes, I'm actually planning to use Route53, but the question still remains unanswered. The thing is that I want to have ns1.mydomain.com and ns2.mydomain.com so that I can give them as name servers to my clients. However even If I use Route53 I'm not sure how to achieve to have ns1 and ns2 to act as vanity name servers. It just doesn't seem possible even with Route53 and I searched the internet to find this out. From my understanding to have ns1 and ns2 I should create glue records, however they should only point to static IP, which is not possible even in Route53.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/675151/72888